# How to debug Dataflow/Apache Beam pipeline DoFn functions in eclipse using direct runner

Tags: eclipse, maven, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, direct-runner

I want to run my pipeline using [direct runner](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/) in eclipse and put a break point in my DoFn functions and debug execution. I tried to setup direct runner with following steps:

1. Add direct runner maven package[image]
2. Setup maven profile for direct runner in pom.xml. My pom.xml has [this profile](https://pastebin.com/19vW4bXM)

`<profiles>
   <profile>
      <id>direct-runner</id>
      <activation>
         <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
            <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0-incubating</version>
         </dependency>
      </dependencies>
   </profile>
</profiles>`

3. I have [this](https://pastebin.com/PunzJKHi) maven plugin under plugin management in my pom.xml

`<pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.4.0</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
          <configuration>
            <cleanupDaemonThreads>false</cleanupDaemonThreads>
            <mainClass>com.MyMainClass</mainClass>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>`

4. Below is a screen shot of my eclipse debug configuration[image] 
   When I run using above debug configuration job starts in GCP dataflow instead of local JVM threads and my breakpoints are never hit.

Comment: I just add a possible solutiuon, anyway it would be useful if you can put ur testing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably is the way how you are creating your pipeline in your test methods.  Try to create the pipeline using the TestPipeline util class like this

```
public TestPipeline p = TestPipeline.create();
```